# Smooth quotients and separation of orbits

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

Consider a unipotent algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ acting polynomially on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Suppose that the quotient exists as an analytical geometric quotient, i.e.,  $\mathbb{C}^n/G$ is a smooth analytic manifold and the quotient map is analytic.  Do $G$-invariants separate the orbits?

Comment: I would recommend trying a more specific title for the post; would "Smooth quotients and separation of orbits" be reasonable? Tags already tell us we're talking about GIT.

Comment: Done. Thx for the advice.